# Request to reopen “'These sort of things': is it grammatical? (2,670,000 hits on Google)”

Tags: discussion

I think the closed question, [“'These sort of things': is it grammatical? (2,670,000 hits on Google)”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70341/these-sort-of-things-is-it-grammatical-2-670-000-hits-on-google) should be reopened.

As Peter Shor said,

> Except that it's not an exact duplicate. This question deals with
>   "these kind of X", with a plural determinant and a singular word from
>   kind/type/sort, and those questions deal with "this kind" or "these
>   kinds". –

Furthermore, this particular question has one good answer citing a good reference that, in my opinion, everyone should read, but a lot of people, probably, wont read it if the etiquette [closed] appears.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me the closed question *is* a duplicate, so I think it was right to close it.

On the other hand, it does have a good answer. I'd rather see one of the mods "merge" it with the original, so at least all the answers are in one place. Then let the best answer win the votes!